# Eclipse, XDebug, PDT not able to map path correctly

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I have XDebug set up on a local vagrant machine and have been using Eclipse and PDT to debug.  Everything has been working fine, but today the debugger has stopped working correctly.  The problem seems to be in the path mapping.  I am using Firefox and the Easiest Xdebug plug-in to fire off a remote debug.  This is still working correctly as the script is picked up by Eclipse and the "Select the local resource that matches the following server path" dialog pops up.  When I was using this over the past few weeks, I was able to select the file from my project.  Now, I'm not given the option of using my project and only have a few (very old) RemoteSystemsTempFiles showing up.  I'm not sure why I'm not allowed to select my project anymore because I haven't done anything to the settings of Eclipse.  I've tried starting Eclipse with the -clean flag, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Any ideas how to figure out why the path mapping isn't showing my project when debug perspective is loaded up?  Here's what I have for my PHP server settings in eclipse:

Name: Default PHP Web Server
Base URL: http://local.dev
Local Web Root: /Users/xxx/Dropbox/joomla-vagrant/www
Path on Server: /home/vagrant/www
Path in Workspace: VagrantJoomla

The script I'm running to fire the debug is http://local.dev/test.php

Please let me know if there is any other info I should be posting and thanks for the help.

-Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out how to get things workable on my set up. When editing the path map, I selected "Path in File System" rather than "Path in Workspace".

This was successful in giving me the following option when the debugger opened: 
/RemoteSystemsTempFiles/LOCALHOST/Users/xxx/Dropbox/joomla-vagrant/www/test.php

-- So, it must have been something with the way my workspace is configured.

--- EDIT ---
After using this setup for a couple of hours, it too broke.  What I ultimately did is just start a new workspace from scratch and so far everything is working correctly